# How to prevent JFX Dialog to hide the application

Tags: java, javafx, modal-dialog

I have a JFX program that should always be maximized covering the desktop,
what happens to me is that when I start a dialog, like

```java
 Alert dlg2 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
 dlg2.setHeaderText("my Dialog");
 dlg2.setContentText("Error: unabvle to load");
 System.err.println("Unable to load ");
 dlg2.showAndWait();
```

The application window hides showing just the alert over the desktop.
I need to keep the application showing hiding windows's desktop

Comment: We are going to have to see a [mcve] that demonstrates exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `initOwner` method might help.

The official [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#initOwner-javafx.stage.Window-) says:

> Specifies the owner Window for this dialog, or null for a top-level,
> unowned dialog. This must be done prior to making the dialog visible.

So setting the proprietary window causes the dialog to display above it.
Try adding this method `dlg2.initOwner(YourStage)` to your alert. Remember that you must enter a parameter of type Stage.

```
Alert dlg2 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
dlg2.setHeaderText("my Dialog");
dlg2.setContentText("Error: unabvle to load");
System.err.println("Unable to load ");
dlg2.initOwner(<YourStage>);
dlg2.showAndWait();
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day!

Comment: "_must enter a parameter of type Stage_" – [Window, not Stage](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#initOwner(javafx.stage.Window)); though Stage is a Window